# Differing tire sizes on tread and side wall

Tags: tire, size

While working on my bike the other day, I noticed that there's what appears to be a tire size on the tread. It says 27.5x2.35

[image]

Thing is ... this is a 29 inch tire. It also says so on the side wall, along with the respective ISO number (60-622)

[image]

This is a Schwalbe Hans Dampf that was factory-fitted on the bike by the manufacturer (Cube).
Full tire details as per Cube:
Schwalbe Hans Dampf, Addix Soft, Kevlar, Super Gravity, Tubeless Easy, 2.35

The front tire is a Schwalbe Magic Mary that has no such marking on the tread, just the correct details on the side wall.

Can someone explain this? An error in the mold in the Schwalbe factory perhabs? Or maybe the numbers mean something completely different?

It's not at all a problem for me. I know for a fact that this is a 29er bike with 29 inch wheels. I'm just curious.

Comment: The mold was probably re-purposed.  Likely if you study the tread carefully you can see a spot where the tread pattern was repeated (with seams of a sort at each end) for about 300mm.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Oh, that's a good point. I'll certainly check for that tomorrow. Please consider adding this as an answer, you might very well be on the right track there. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an error to me - its either 29" or 27.5" with no ambiguity.   It is unusual to see details embedded in the tread, I've never seen it in person.

You could choose to highlight the correct size details with a white paint pen, and/or file the wrong marking off with some careful strokes of a file.   Or ride till it wears off :)

Comment: Nah, I'm not going to remove that wrong size on the tread. I like that little bit of weirdness. Makes the bike slightly more unique while the tire lasts :) And it might help me prove my ownership, should I ever need to. Thanks for your reply.